# How to update a list of mapped object in dynamodb without using index?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

Below is my dynamodb structure:

```
`Employees:[{
             emp_id: '110005',
             Name: 'Sam'
           },
           { 
             emp_id: '110007',
             Name: 'Ram'
           }]`
```

Now, I want to update name of employee with `emp_id = 110007` but not using their index.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: `but not using their index` - then what would you like to use? Name itself? Did you also index the name prop?

Comment: What is the primary key on that table?

Comment: I want to use `emp_id` to update the `Name` attribute